# How can I get a prepay SIM card before going to Greece?

Tags: cellphones, greece

I'm going to Greece with my girlfriend, but she's going for a conference and I'm just tagging along.

I'd like to get a couple of prepaid SIM cards before I go so that she can get in touch with me when she'd finished with the conference.

Is there a way to get prepaid SIM cards for Greece from the UK?

I've looked at [Holiday Phone](http://www.holidayphone.co.uk/), but their prices seem extortionate compared to what I've managed to piece together from various websites which seem to only have been half localized.

Internet would be a plus but it's not a requirement.

Comment: any particular reason for getting it before, not upon arrival?

Comment: We are arriving at 3AM and my girlfriend is going to be attending a conference the next day while I wander about Athens. Want to have SIM cards so we can get on touch when she's done.

Comment: Just for the community´s information... You can find prepaid cards in the kiosks "periptero / περίπτερο" that you can find open 24/7! No need to walk into a mobile store. Just ask for a Vodafone card that comes with some amount prepaid and you can top up anywhere later.

Answer (score 7):

I after extensive research, I bought a prepaid SIM card from www.maxroam.com for roaming around Europe.

I am traveling around Eastern Europe (in Bulgaria right now). The prepaid SIM is based out of Ireland I believe.

Acquiring a prepaid SIM specifically for Greece I imagine would involve walking into the mobile store and physically signing papers.

My guess is your best bet is contacting someone in Greece to do that for you. If you are dead set on getting a prepaid SIM specifically for Greece, perhaps hiring a virtual assistant in Athens for this task?

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of any travellers who come to an EU country from outside the EU, please note that as of July 2017 there are two new EU regulation, which are good and bad at the same time.

The good part is that within the EU roaming fees are pretty much abandoned. That means if you travel through multiple EU countries pick one SIM card for your Internet needs and it will do. It will also work well when it comes to outgoing calls. Just you will be assigned a GSM number from the country the SIM card belongs to which means it may be expensive for other people to call you. If this is not an issue, you'd be fine ...

Except ...

The rules on making sure each SIM card is clearly registered to a person have become stricter. In the past you often could buy a SIM card in a kiosk, a supermarket or even from a vending machine, register it with your name and a pretty arbitrary address (use a phone dictionary or google any address) and you'd be all set. Now they want to see papers.

That has led to for example some supermarkets to even stop selling SIM cards as they don't want to go through that hassle. You'll not have an issue to walk into any GSM shop, show your passwort and have a card activated for you, but as the original poster wrote: It means to know where to find one, finding it open ...